# joomla 3 dropdown list box with search option

Tags: php, joomla

I am creating joomla 3 custom component,In that am creating product category list box by using custom fieldtype **(mycomponent/models/fields/productcategory.php)**. It also showing the product cagetory in right manner.

But I need to display the product category select list box with search option like position field in module manager. I have include my coding below

```
    `class JFormFieldProductCat extends JFormFieldList
    {
    /**
     * The form field type.
     *
     * @var         string
     * @since       1.6
     */
    protected $type = 'ProductCat';

    /**
     * Method to get the field options.
     *
     * @return      array   The field option objects.
     * @since       1.6
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
            // Initialize variables.
            $options = array();

            $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

            $query->select('id, productcat');
            $query->from('#__productcats AS a');
            $query->order('a.productcat');
            $query->where('published = 1');

            // Get the options.
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $options = array();
            $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '0', 'Select Category Name');

            $result = $db->loadObjectList();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
      $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row->id, $row->productcat);
            }
        // Check for a database error.
            if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
                    JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
            }


            return $options;
    }
    }`
```

Comment: you want ur o/p like this -> http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @ashish yes select2 is better than selectlistbox like this (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) do you know, how select2 will implemented in our custom component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the **soultion for select listbox** with search option

here the link (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) i found the solution for selectbox search,here is the coding.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $( "#jform_fk_productcat" ).combobox();
         $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
         $( "#jform_fk_productcat" ).toggle();
         });
         });
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $( "#jform_fk_product_code" ).combobox();
       $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
       $( "#jform_fk_product_code" ).toggle();
      });
     });
```

but i sloved better than this.. refer this url for better solution 
[in joomla 3 how to include auto complete search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668866/in-joomla-3-how-to-include-auto-complete-search/18680167#18680167)