# in joomla 3 how to include auto complete search

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, joomla

I am creating custom component,in that In that am creating product category list box by using custom **fieldtype (mycomponent/models/fields/productcategory.php).** It also showing the product cagetory in right manner.

i need to create **select listbox with auto complete search** like position field in module manager..

Any one know the solution..

Comment: have you tried anything of your own yet?

Comment: ya i am try to add auto search which done like [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).It working fine in core php,am trying to add it on my custom component

Comment: @Lodder do u know how position field working in module manager  like that only i need to do in my component

Comment: you need a custom field type, see moduleposition in administrator/components/com_modules/models/fields/moduleposition.php

Comment: Is it frontend or backend ?

Comment: administrator\components\com_modules\models in this url ,didn't have any custom field.It only have module file and form folder.

Comment: @user1876234 i need it in my admin side only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem using [`select.js`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#basics).

The jQuery coding is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".productcat").change(function(){
    fk_productcat = $("#" + this.id).val();
    //alert(fk_productcat);
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:'index.php?option=com_gwerp&task=stocks.getListArticles',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'fk_productcat': fk_productcat
      }
    }).done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      jQuery(".product").html(msg);
      jQuery( ".product" ).val(msg).trigger( "liszt:updated" );
      jQuery("#jform_fk_product_code").select2();
    })
  })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#jform_fk_productcat").select2();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#jform_fk_product_code").select2();
});
```

I called Ajax file by refer [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383822/how-to-change-select-list-from-another-using-ajax-in-joomla).